# RX.JS equivalent of fromArray?

Tags: arrays, rxjs, operators, element

Rx.js seems to have an operator [`toArray`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/toArray). What takes something from an array and emits the elements of the array? For instance, if I do,

```
ajax('localhost/foo')
```

and that returns returns `{foo: [1,2,3]}`. How can I map that to something that emits `1`, `2`, and `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found found `mergeMap()` works, but I don't know if there is a better way,

```
ajax$.pipe(
  mergeMap( x => x.response.events )
).subscribe( x => console.log("foo", x) );
```

Comment: The return type of the mergeMap function should be an observable, not a raw value - I would expect what you have done here to cause a compiler error unless x.response.events is an observable type. Antoine's answer looks correct to me.

Comment: @MarkHughes The return type is `ObservableInput` which is defined as `SubscribableOrPromise<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T>`. RxJS allows you to use these types in many places where you would expect only observables to be accepted.

Comment: Good point @abetteroliver - I hadn't realised the ArrayLike/Iterable were accepted too - that is why this answer /does/ work - [the docs explain](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html) that returning an ArrayLike/Iterable from the mergeMap function will cause the result to be the emission of each value from the iterable in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `from` which convert an iterable into an observable.

`toArray` is not what you are looking for: it buffers all the values of an observable and emit them once the observable is complete.
See: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html

In your case you already have an observable which is your ajax call. It's an observable itsel even if it returns only one value and then immediatly complete.

If you map the value produced by your observable (the response) to another observable with `from`, you will have an observable of observable (which is called an high order observable). 
See: https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885

To have a simple observable of numbers you will need to also use a combinaison operators (`merge`, `switch`, `concat`). Any of it will do the work.

```
ajax$.pipe(
  concatMap(x => from(x.response.events)),
).subscribe(x => console.log("foo", x)) // 1, then 2, then 3
```

Comment: It's worth noting that for an observable which emits a single result (e.g. a regular HTTP request), any of concatMap, flatMap, mergeMap, switchMap will do the same thing. Their subtle differences only come into play when dealing with a source observable that emits multiple items.